# Ctrl-V not working in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-office-2013

I am running Word 2013 on a Windows 7 (this is a work computer) and I can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> just produces a slight 'ding' sound and does not paste.  I have to use the right click menu.

I do not have this problem in any other program (including other office apps, all work fine).

I did a search and found several possible solutions, none have worked.

I tried:

-See file - options - language under "Choose Display and help languages" set both to english and click on set as default, then restart the office app

-In the Customize Keyboard dialog box, verify that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is assigned to EditCopy and that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is assigned to EditPaste. (To display the dialog box, click File tab | Options | Customize Ribbon | Customize.)

Any other suggestions?  This is very frustrating.

Comment: Go into notepad, or if you prefer - excel. Type in some short text, then do the Ctrl-C and then Ctrl-V.  Assuming it does paste, then bring up a blank word doc and then do a Crtl-V, if it does paste, look at what you are coping and see what is going on. In a blank word document,try text, graphic, etc. and do a copy/paste.  Not the only reason, but I have seen this before where the issue is coming from the source document that is being copied.